# gRPC server streaming message by ID

Tags: c#, .net-core, streaming, grpc

Currently, I have a gRPC Application that has a message CreateSimpleOrderRequest:

```
message CreateSimpleOrderRequest {
    string broker = 1;
    string account = 2;
    SimpleOrderType order_type = 3;
    string symbol = 4;
    Side side = 5;
    int64 quantity = 6;
}
```

After sending a "CreateSimpleOrderRequest", the client can subscribe to this Simple Order and receive any updates that were received by another service.

Simple Order message:

```
message SimpleOrder {
    string strategy_id = 1;
    string account = 2;
    string broker = 3;
    int64 executed_quantity = 4;
    double price = 7;
    double avg_price = 9;
    int64 quantity = 10;
    Side side = 13;
    StrategyStatus status = 14;
    string symbol = 16;
}
```

Simple Order Service:

```
service SimpleOrderService {
    rpc Create (CreateSimpleOrderRequest) returns (StrategyResponse);
    rpc Subscribe (SubscribeRequest) returns (stream SimpleOrder);
```

If any simple order that I created over the day receives an update, I will receive a message of this updated simple order with it's strategy_id (since it is a SimpleOrder message param).

The question is: if I should return all the Simple Orders, as soon as they are updated or I should be using a strategy_id to filter which Simple Order I want to to receive a message?

*Notice that the only thing that matters here is to follow the best practices in gRPC/Socket server streaming connections*

Comment: Please read [ask]. I think you're the only one who can answer your own question. How are we to know what your requirements are? It sounds like you don't actually want to receive a notification for every update, so proceed accordingly.

Comment: This is not a "best practices" kind of question. The question really is, do you need all of the notices or just the ones for specific Id's? If the later, then by all means, apply the filter. The Google is a better place to ask these kinds of questions: https://www.google.com/search?q=best+practices+in+gRPC%2FSocket+server+streaming+connections